# Why does the alignment of a class member variable in one module differ from that in another module?

Tags: class, variables, gcc, alignment, visual-studio-2019

I am porting a Windows C++ program to Linux using Visual Studio 2019, WSL Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and GCC (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0.
Compiling x64.
In Windows it works fine, but not in Linux.
Stripped-down source files:
In header file:

```
class CDetail {
public:
CDetail();
~CDetail();
CDetail *Function(void);
char m_code;
char m_name[100];
};
```

In module A:

```
  CDetail *pointer = My Detail;
  pointer->Function();
```

In module B:

```
CDetail* CDetail::Function()
{
  char *name = m_name;
  .
  .
}
```

When debugging:
(The values are actual values for an expanded class)
In module A the value of **pointer** is 0x5555557d72b9
The value of **&(pointer->m_name)** is 0x5555557d72b9

In module B the value of **this** is 0x5555557d72b9 (as expected)
The value of **&m_name** is 0x5555557d72b6 (off by 3 bytes)

This looks like an alignment problem. How can it be solved?

Comment: Why do you expect the address of `m_name` be the same of the `CDetail` object? Where did the `m_code` member go? Maybe modules were compiled against different versions of the class?

Comment: The address of m_name must be the same as that of pointer->m_name since it refers to the same instance of the object. The address of m_code is the same. A build-all does not solve the problem.